# Replacing failed hardware in a hyper-converged cluster node

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, hardware, cluster, datacenter

Is it possible to replace failed physical components (such as disk, RAM, or power supply) in a hyper-converged node (such as VXrail or Nutanix) without taking the node offline?

Comment: Okay, the most recent edit made this a bad question.

Comment: as mentioned earlier, it's a hardware thing. Nutanix - Dell PE/ Supermicro hardware. VXRail - Dell FX (Most sure). Keep in mind that it's still an all-in-one solution so if you brick the node while swapping out the RAM stick it's not going to be covered neither by warranty nor by support.

Comment: Care to explain why it's a bad question? A downvote and negative comment by themselves aren't very helpful in improving the content on this site.

Comment: @sturdyerde Because you already received two appropriate answers and edited the question without acknowledging them. What was unacceptable about the answers you've received so far?

Comment: Couldn't a moderator have stated that or simply rejected the edit? Since there has already been some meta conversations about the question, my goal was to clarify it without actually changing the heart of the question. This should make it more clearly applicable to the general server audience and not appear to be about any one specific vendor's technology.

Comment: Again, marking this as off topic for being a question about "installation, configuration, or diagnostic help" seems like a hasty judgement that was done without understanding the intent of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about the question here:

Hyperconverged solutions are focused on combining virtualization compute and storage resources together.

These are still built atop commodity servers (Supermicro, Dell, HP, etc.), so the reasonable expectation is that you can hot-swap disks, but you likely would not be able hot-swap RAM.

The point of these solutions is that the redundancies allow for complete evacuation (or failure) of a node, so hot-swap of an individual component isn't an absolute necessity.

Answer (score 3):

Hot swapping components is a hardware feature, and has nothing to do with the software installed on the hardware. If your machines allow for cpu and ram hotswap then you should be able to do just that. But that's not really a heard of  option of course.

Comment: you hypervisor should also support cpu and ram hot swap

Comment: obviously, but hardware support for such things is much more rare than software.